# Why doesn't this javascript function have access to the variables in the closure above it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive in Angular to show whether or not an element is in the viewport (i.e. whether the user has scrolled to it).

However while I thought that closures would give me access to the element that originally defined the scroll listener, I can't seem to access it:

```
MyApp.directive("inview",  ($window) ->
  link = (scope, element, attrs) ->
    sourceElement = element

    processScrollEvent = (event) ->
      console.log("They see me scrollin'");
      # once I can access the sourceElement then I'll do the
      # calculations to find out whether it's in the viewport

      # However sourceElement is not defined in this scope
      # ... how can I access it?


    angular.element($window).bind "scroll", processScrollEvent
  {
    link: link
  }
)
```

How can I reference the original element in the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

In CoffeeScript, you can use the `=>` notation for a function instead of the classic `->`. It will capture `this` and bind it to your new function.

Try like this:

```
link = (scope, element, attrs) ->
    @sourceElement = element // '@' is the same as 'this.'

    processScrollEvent = (event) =>
      console.log("They see me scrollin'");
      console.log(@sourceElement);
```

Comment: Guillaume - I thought that worked but I'm not sure it does. If there are two elements on the page the value of @sourceElement is always the second element. It seems to be redefined each time. Do you have any thoughts? Also I still wonder why closures don't work as normal - it should have access to the variables in the scope it was defined...